# Binding a collection of object to a NSTextView

Tags: swift, binding, nstextview

I have a collection of the following object:

```
class Dialog {
    var speaker = ""
    var text = ""
}
```

What is the best way to bind the collection (`[Dialog]`) to a *NSTextView* ?

I want to have bidirectional binding:

- Editing the *NSTextView* update the collection
- Editing the collection update the *NSTextView*